# promise from fetch not resolving properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise, fetch

So I have this method that I use to call the all purpose fetch method I defined in a separate js file:

```
export function detailedView(request,token)
{
    let endpoint = 'api/v1/cbn/inventory/GetDetailRequest?RequestNo='+request['RequestNo'];

    let header = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": "Bearer "+ token
    }

    return dispatch => {
        return fetchAPI(endpoint,'POST', header, null)
        .then((json) => {
            dispatch(receiveDetails()); 
        })
        .catch((error) => {     //PROBLEM IS HERE
            console.log("error message: " + error);
            dispatch(receiveEmptyDetails());
        });
    }
}
```

the marked spot in that code is always called for some reason although the fecth function below always end up at the spot marked below:

```
export function fetchAPI(endpoint, method, header, data) {
    let url = 'http://10.64.2.149:8082/' + endpoint;

    let options = {
            method: method,
            headers: header,
            body: stringify(data)
          };

    return fetch(url, options)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
                .then((json) => {
                    console.log(json, response) //AT THIS POINT RESPONSE STATUS IS 200, SHOWN IN THE SCREENCAP BELOW
                    if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 201) {
                        return json; 
                    } else if (response.status === 408) {
                        throw('Request Timeout');
                      }
                    else if (response.status === 400){
                          throw ('Bad request');
                    }
                     else {
                        if (json.errors) {
                            throw(json.errors);
                        } else {
                            throw('unknown error');
                        }
                    }
                })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (typeof error.message !== 'undefined') {
                throw(error.message);
            } else if (typeof error === 'string') {
                throw(error);
            } else if (Object.keys(error)) {
                let errStr = '';
                let errors = _.omit(error, ['column', 'line', 'sourceURL'])

                _.forEach(errors, function (value) {
                    errStr += value + '.\n';
                });
                throw (errStr);
            } else {
                throw('unknown error');
            }
        });
}

module.exports = { fetchAPI };
```

[image: CONSOLE OUTPUT]

I have another method that does exactly the same as this (just with different endpoint, but everything else is a copy and paste), which utilizes the same fetch function above, and the problem never appeared.

But as you can see from the printed console log (last line), for some reason this bit always resolves to `catch` instead of `then`, calling it a `reference error` as if the request wasn't successful.

Anyone has any idea what's happening here?

Comment: Likely `dispatch(receiveDetails())` thrown an error. Add catch blocks in `receiveDetails` to see where it occurs.

Comment: are you waiting for a json? if the response is a text and you have this 'response.json()' it would fail to fetch

Comment: @ErichMenezes yes it's supposed to be waiting for a json, I've logged inside the `if(response.status===200)` too and it did return the `json`, it's just once it's back to the `detailedView()` method that the promise is resolved as an error. So I'm suspecting that now return `response.json()` is the one that's not resolving properly.

Comment: @riwu I see what u mean, my bad, silly mistake, I edited that part in hurry and forgot to replace the parameters properly, thanks for the insight! :)

Comment: Your screenshot shows `request is not defined` but you claim you end up in catch after calling `fetchAPI`. However; `fetchAPI` does not contain any code accessing a variable named `request` so the error is likely in `dispatch(receiveDetails())` since you didn't post any of the code of the `receiveDetails` function it's impossible to solve but I can guess that function is trying to access a variable named `request` that has not been defined (not the same as undefined)

Comment: You're falling into the promise-as-callback antipattern here. You might consider refactoring a bit.

Comment: @HMR yes u are right, as I mentioned in my comment reply to riwu, I edited that part yesterday and forgot to pass the correct parameter to `receiveDetails()` and when that function fails to build the action object in that function, it moves on to `catch` where my console log was triggered and that's why I was under the assumption it was going to `catch` straight from `fetchAPI`, silly mistake, sorry to have misled everyone!

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment reply to @riwu, my mistake was simple:

I edited my code in hurry where I moved the `action object` from being passed to `dispatch` as parameter into the `receiveDetails()` function as a return object. 
Then I passed that function like so `dispatch(receiveDetails())` instead.

However, I forgot to pass the correct parameters to `receiveDetails()`, the call should've been `receiveDetails(request,json.data)` instead of what I wrote on my post above.

Then, when that `receiveDetails()` fails to build the `action object`, it moves on to `catch`, where my console log was triggered and that's why I was under the assumption that it was going to `catch` straight from `fetchAPI`.

Such a silly mistake, sorry to have misled everyone in this post and thanks for the insightful comments! :D